# Geography in 3D perspective

Tags: geography, geographics

I would like to build a `GeoGraphics` map showing a z-elevated perspective (e.g. the view from a plane). Specifically, I'm looking to use multiple `GeoMarker`'s (with custom graphics) in the pseudo-3D perspective.

For example, consider this plot of the Eiffel Tower:

[image]

I would like to reproduce it in a 3D perspective like this:

[image]

Both examples come from google maps, I’m not sure if this is possible in 11.3, but would love to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use an orthographic with a custom centering:

```
GeoGraphics[
  Entity["Building", "EiffelTower::5h9w8"], 
  GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{-30.858`, 2.295`}]}, 
  GeoZoomLevel -> 18, 
  GeoRange -> {{48.852`, 48.872`}, {2.2895`, 2.2995`}}
]
```

[image]

Note that this does incorporate the curvature of the earth and will be noticeable over larger areas.

If you're after something flat, you could always inset the tiles in 3D and pick custom `View*` values. Note I pad the range to allow the map to be seen at an angle:

```
im = GeoImage[
  Entity["Building", "EiffelTower::5h9w8"], 
  "StreetMapNoLabels", 
  GeoZoomLevel -> 17, 
  GeoRange -> {{48.852`, 48.872`}, {2.285`, 2.305`}}
];

{x, y} = ImageDimensions[im];

Graphics3D[
  {Texture[im], EdgeForm[], Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {x, 0, 0}, {x, y, 0}, {0, y, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
  Background -> Black,
  Boxed -> False, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  ViewAngle -> 0.03233723833101999`, 
  ViewCenter -> {{0.5`, 0.5`, 0.5`}, {1.4456583184354543`, 0.7806170277104297`}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.076788325190908`, -3.1635309749673284`, 0.5316001064285271`}, 
  ViewVertical -> {0.00011882147473772082`, -0.00015290540260965785`, 0.9999999812506973`}
]
```

[image]

---

Here's a way to 'lift' a `GeoGraphics` object into 3D. My solution is probably not robust but works for simple cases:

```
GeoGraphics3D[args__] := Block[{g2d, g3d, ε = .0001},
  g2d = GeoGraphics[args][[1, 1]] /. {___, Opacity[0], ___} -> {};
  g3d = g2d /. {
    expr : _[VertexTextureCoordinates, _] :> expr,
    Inset[g_, {x_, y_}, opos_, Offset[o_]] :> Inset[g, RotationTransform[\[CurlyEpsilon], {0, -1, 0}]@{x, y, 0}, opos, .5 o],
    {x_Real, y_} :> RotationTransform[\[CurlyEpsilon], {0, -1, 0}][{x, y, 0}]
  };

  Graphics3D[
   g3d,
   Boxed -> False,
   ImageSize -> Large,
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}
  ]
]
```

Example:

```
eif = Entity["Building", "EiffelTower::5h9w8"];

Show[
  GeoGraphics3D[
    {GeoMarker[eif], Text[Style["Eiffel Tower", ColorData[112, 1], 14], eif, {0, 1}]}, 
    GeoRange -> Quantity[1000, "Meters"], 
    GeoZoomLevel -> 17
  ], 
  ViewAngle -> 2°, 
  ViewPoint -> {1.75`, -2.85`, 0.55`}
]
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't working with my geomarkers, is there some hack for that?

Comment: Ah I overlooked that part of your question, sorry. I’m assuming you want them orthogonal to the map facing the view point?

Comment: Yup, just like that (and a drop shadow if possible ;))

Comment: I was hasty in accepting, without GeoMarkers I can't do what I wanted - if you can add that I'll accept it

Comment: No worries for not accepting -- turns out I didn't fully address your question!

Comment: @M.R. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks this is great! Is there anyway to make the text seem less blurry and skewed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91227/discussion-between-m-r-and-chip-hurst).