# Possible to create a 3D GeoRegionValuePlot?

Tags: graphics3d, visualization, geographics

I can create a zip-code-based 2D GeoRegionValuePlot, as follows:

```
test = {{Interpreter["ZIPCode"]["ZIP 04096"], 
15}, {Interpreter["ZIPCode"]["ZIP 04345"], 
35}, {Interpreter["ZIPCode"]["ZIP 04530"], 55}} 
GeoRegionValuePlot[test]
```

=>
[image]

I'd like to create 3D versions of such maps, by which I mean that, for each zip code with data, there would be a column whose 2D cross-section would correspond to the shape of the zip code region, and whose height would be proportional to the value for that zip code.  I'd also like the option for the value to be automatically put in or on each column.

How might I go about doing this in MMA?

Here are a couple of examples (which may or may not be by zip code, but still illustrate the idea):

[image]

Source:  Constantine Valhouli and Cat Callaghan, Hammersmith Group,
https://medium.com/re-form/nycs-housing-cost-myth-9dce6052c139  See also:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158112/is-there-any-web-gl-js-libraries-for-creating-3d-bar-overlap-city-map

---

[image]

Source: http://agl.pw/examples/cesium/hobart.html

Comment: closely related / possible duplicate: [Map of United States as a 3D histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57872/125)

Comment: @kglr Thanks! halmir's answer looks intriguing, but I couldn't run his code in MMA 12.  I got errors starting with the cell defining the variable "divisions":  "EntityList::noent: Entity[AdministrativeDivision,{Except[Alaska|Hawaii],UnitedStates}] is not an entity."

Comment: you can try `divisions = DeleteCases[EntityList[ Interpreter["AdministrativeDivisionClass"]["US States"]], Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Alaska"|"Hawai",     "UnitedStates"}]]
`

Comment: Have a look at the [`CountryPlot3D` package](https://github.com/simonschmidt/Mathematica-CountryPlot).

Comment: Mildly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193444/geography-in-3d-perspective